# How can I lock/unlock all files in a folder in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

To prevent accidental undesired edits I want to lock my code, but going file by file is unpractical, how can I lock whole folders?

Answer (score 0):

Is [Locking and Unlocking Files and Folders](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/locking-and-unlocking-files-and-folders.html) what you're looking for. There is a way where you can lock files to avoid overwriting changes.